# mysql - how to enter the record with only whitespace

Tags: php, mysql

I want to enter the record with white-space as a record in MySQL. I had tried to enter it through shell and phpmyadmin, the record enters but when I try to retrieve the record it returns as null. I had also set the column null = no even then returns nothing.

code is below through shell and php:

```
insert into first_replace(to_replace, with_replace) values(".", " ");
```

Comment: Can you provide an SQL sample of how you are trying to insert this?

Comment: @Vineet1982 Show code, everything, sql and the php code.

Comment: through shell -> insert into first_replace(to_replace, with_replace) values(".", " ");

Comment: @Vineet1982 How are you determining that it's null for return?

Comment: After fetching<script>alter('<? echo "a".$row["with_replace"]."bc"; ?>')</script>

Comment: How are you retrieving the data? Are you running a query within MySQL like "SELECT with_replace FROM first_replace WHERE to_replace = '.'" and it is returning NULL? Or are you running a query from within PHP and PHP is saying it is returning FALSE?

Comment: @vnieet use whitespace in string format like i have tried now just..INSERT INTO `test`.`test` (`test`) VALUES ('_'); here _ = whitespace as space is getting trimmed in this comment..

Comment: @GitsD if you check the above code you will find the insert statement is same

Comment: yeah @vineet but i tried in phpmyadmin and it works. from there i pasted the code here...

Comment: @GitsD It is inserting but not to retrieve it as it will return nothing

Answer (score -1):

when creating mysql table row enable NULL or edit row and enable NULL

Comment: By setting null or not null same result